# Find Non Duplicate entries in Excel

Tags: excel

I Have A column which contains both unique and duplicate values .

Example ColumnA :1 to CoulmA:1000

What formula can be used to find only the non duplicate entries.

Can we use Vlookup if so how ?

Answer (score 2):

Extending **sten's** suggestion:

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1,1,"")
```

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1,1+MAX($B$1:B1),"")
```

and copy down.

this will create a unique, sequential ID for all the unique records in column **A**

Finally, in **C1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),B:B,0)),"")
```

Should look like:

[image: mypic]

The same result can be achieved with AutoFilter followed by Copy/Paste.

Answer (score 1):

```
=countif(A:A,A1)
```

Drag that sucker down and take everything with a 1. You can reduce the mental load on yourself by selecting only the ones which are 1.

```
=if(countif(A:A,A1)<>1,"",1)
```