# Find Non Duplicate entries in Excel without using data from more than one column

Tags: excel-formula

I've already found a solution but with using countif formula in column B and then, formula: =IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),B:B,0)),"")

[Find Non Duplicate entries in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836735/find-non-duplicate-entries-in-excel)

but, what I need is to get all data in an array formula in one step because I'm trying to get data in a dynamic list without repeated data. Maybe it already exists other way to do it but I've not found any solution yet.
I know, I can do it with macro but I want to do it with only one formula if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have Office 365 Excel, use UNIQUE().

Comment: Thank you so much! So close, so far...